# TextBox inside eclipse's draw2d figure

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef, draw2d

Is there any way to include a Text Box inside a draw2d figure? (a code example would be nice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily, and if you're just using Draw2d without GEF, then I don't think it's possible.

With GEF, you can make use of a `DirectEditManager` in an Edit Part, and create an Edit Policy (extending `DirectEditPolicy`, installed with the key `EditPolicy.DIRECT_EDIT_ROLE`) to allow a direct edit to be performed on a figure.

You could create a figure which extends `Label` that is styled to look like a text box, and activate (by overriding `performRequest` in the Edit Part) editing upon selection.

This [Schema Diagram example](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-editor/gef-schema-editor.html) contains this type of functionality (and more importantly, the code!), although the figure used for edit (`EditableLabel`) isn't styled to look like a text box, and the activation itself is on double-click rather than selection.

It may point you in the right direction though.